# Cloud Computing and MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cloud

I have written some MATLAB code that classifies sounds, based on an Artificial intelligence approach.

Now I would like to use the same program on the cloud.

Do I need I convert the code to some other programming language, or is it possible to use the same MATLAB code on the cloud?

Comment: you probably want to port it to another language...

Comment: it depends, what exactly you need!!!

Comment: I've edited this useful question to make it less opinion-based - it's no longer "should I..." but "is it necessary to...", which has an objective answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to move your application to the cloud in order to speed it up by running it on a cloud computing resource, it's possible to parallelize your application using [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/parallel-computing/), and then to execute that on instances of [MATLAB Distributed Computing Server](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/distriben/) that are running in the cloud, such as on Amazon EC2. MathWorks have [resources](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/discovery/matlab-ec2.html) on their website, including a white paper, on how to do this. Note that, unusually for MathWorks products, if you do this it's possible to pay for the instances of MATLAB Distributed Computing Server by the hour, rather than having to buy an expensive permanent license (speak to your account manager to find out about that payment option).

If you'd like to run your code on the cloud just for convenience, or to offload it from your computer, rather than to speed it up, then if you have a MATLAB license you can use [MATLAB Mobile](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/mobile/) (for iPhone or Android) to run your code on MathWorks' own cloud resources, for free (including storage of up to 500MB of your data).

Of course, you may find that for various reasons you eventually think it's better to recode it all in a different language - but there are several options you can try out pretty quickly before committing to that lengthy task.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if parallel computing toolbox is not enough you can look at [MATLAB Distributed Computing Server](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-ec2.html).